# How to get the session id from NSURLConnection - IOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, session, nsurlconnection

How to get the session id from NSURLConnection?

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by session id? What have you tried?

Comment: Using web service, we can create some session and will provide some session id for login service. If I use NSURLConnection to connect some API, some session has been created. Can IOS can capture the session id?

Answer (score 0):

Use delegates of NSURLConnection to get session id if your request gets feedback as session id:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:
    (NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // Discard all previously received data.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:
(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to the receivedData.
[receivedData appendData:data];     
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Connection succeeded in downloading the request.
    NSLog( @"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [receivedData length] );

    // Convert received data into string.
    receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData 
        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //receivedString will have session id if request is appropriate
    NSLog( @"From connectionDidFinishLoading: %@", receivedString );

    // release the connection, and the data object
    [conn release];
    [receivedData release];
}
```

You have to set Protocol NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate in .h file